# Can't install Opencv on raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, opencv, pip, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm using the raspberry pi 4 on visual studio code and whenever I enter the command `pip install opencv-python` in the terminal, after 40 mins I get the error message

```
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-install/python/cv2/config-3.py'
      [end of output]
 
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have found a post on the same problem but the suggestion was to upgrade pip and try reinstalling opencv but that hasn't worked either. I'm using python 3.9.2 as an interpreter

Edit:
When I use the command `pip3 install --no-use-pep517 opencv-python` I get the error:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-zwr61c7o/opencv-python_1867909748974f69a8333e238206f9df/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
          import skbuild
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: can you try `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`  and `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip` then do `sudo pip3 install opencv-python`

Comment: I believe OpenCV-python has a build/wheel for 64 bit ARM. that installs without trouble. your linux might be 32 bit.

Comment: @Hackaholic, I tried what you suggested but I'm getting the same error

Comment: sudo apt install opencv-python4.6.x.x or sudo apt install opencv-python4.7.0

Comment: @toyotaSupra, both commands gave error "Unable to locate package"